# Return Rxjs Observable that receives a value after some condition is fulfilled

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular-http-interceptors

I'm implementing an interface that has a function that returns Observable.
I also need to pass some value to the Observable, but it may take some time to receive that value.

How can I still return the Observable and also make it wait for the needed value?

To be more specific, I'm implementing an HttpInterceptor and I want to set a token to the request header.
The token value could be unavailable, so need to wait a little (asynchronously) and try again, until the value is received.
Then set the token in the request header and continue.

How can I implement such mechanism?

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) { }

  getToken(callback) {
    let token = this.tokenService.getToken();
    if (!token) {
      // a valid token wasn't received. wait a little and try again
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.getToken(callback); //recursive call
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      // found valid token
      callback(token);
    }
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // this part should set req when a token is received, but it is asynchronous
    this.getToken((token) => {
      req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token)});
    });

    // this returns Observable. I must return Observable, but req is not ready at this point
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is use RxJs operators. Using [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) should be a good solution here. Essentially in this case, switchMap allows you to chain dependent observables together and only return the inner observable. It should look something like this:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { 
    return getToken.pipe(
        switchMap(token => {
            req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token)});
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    );
}
```

Please note, You'll need to adjust your getToken to return an observable as well in order for this to work.

Comment: in line 5 you need to `return next.handle(req);` :)

Comment: Thanks @joshrathke Looks promising, but I'm not sure how to adjust getToken to return an observable, with the fact it has timeout and recursive call. Could you please add some code?

Comment: `Observable.create(observer => this.getToken(token => { observer.next(token); observer.complete(); }))`

Comment: Works great! Thank you joshrathke and amakhrov!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems that we have callback from `getToken` and observable from `intercept`. It is better to always use observable if possible.

We could convert `getToken(callback)` to use observable. RxJS has `retryWhen` operator that we could use to handle retry.

```js
getToken() {
 const tokenFromService = of(this.tokenService.getToken()); // convert to observable

 return tokenFromService
  .pipe(
    map(token => {
      if (!token) {
        throw new Error('token is not specified'); // it will be caught by retryWhen
      }

      return token;
    }),
    retryWhen(error => {
      return error
        .pipe(
          tap(() => console.log('error happened, retry request token')), 
          delay(1000)
        )
    })
  )
}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.getToken()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(token => {
          const modifiedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token)});
          return next.handle(modifiedReq);
        })
      )      
}
```

Hope it helps

Reference:

- [retryWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen)